# Are there planets with a greater gravitational pull in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, physics, gravity

In all the movies, humans can walk normally on all planets and moons they visit, as if the gravity was similar everywhere. Is this really so? Are any planets with greater gravity represented? Which one has the greatest gravity?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Heavy_gravity

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for your comment. However the link doesn't give a specific answer, as I cannot find the gravity of each planet (in number of g force or similar), neither the one with the greatest gravity.

Comment: But, a planet can't use the force.

Answer (score 4):

An Example of a "Heavy Gravity Planets" :

- [Sirpar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sirpar)
- [Ergeshui](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ergeshui) *Legends*

There was also [The Star Wars Planets Collection](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Planets_Collection) which had a lot of information about planets.

A planet/object's surface gravity is a relation to its mass and radius (all relative to earth's).

```
SurfaceGravity=(mass/(radius*radius));
```

Quantifying a planet's surface gravity in Star Wars is complicated for a variety of reasons:

1. In the fictional universe, there are fictitious compounds of unknown chemical makeup and, therefore, unknown mass (ex. Tibanna Gas).
2. Most current methods for determining a planet's mass involve observing its movement and relating that movement to another object (ex. Distant Star and planet orbiting star).

The best way to do this, without a cannon source, would be to find **real** planets of similar size and composition to planets in Star Wars and through some math wizardry, derive a number using similar methods as to how we would do it with a planet of known size and mass.

Interestingly, Han, Chewie and Liea are able to land and walk on an asteroid with no apparent issues; implying, that the smaller asteroid has an Earth-like surface gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly certain there is no canon source however I would have to say the planet with the highest gravity that they visit in the movies has to be Bespin seeing as how it is a gas giant  :D

As an aside all human inhabited or inhabitable celestial objects would have to have a gravity somewhere around baseline (I think gravity has something to do with an objects ability to retain an atmosphere as well)

Comment: Seeing how any vessel with size ranging from one-seat fighter to cruiser to a moon-sized station has artificial gravity, one can assume that habitats can be equipped with it as well. At least high tech ones like a city floating above a gas giant. That would not apply to shacks on Tatooine and such, of course.